# Selenium access element outside DOM

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm writing automated test using Selenium WebDriver and ruby. I faced with such problem:

I need to close popup, but close-button for popup is outside DOM. In DOM I have `div` element with `class 'promotional-wrapper'` and this element have attribute `data-mage-init='{"promoPopUp": {"url": {"getDataUrl": url from where DOM is updated with new nodes}}}'` This div is responsible for getting popup into the page.
How to access element not directly attached to DOM?

Classic methods to get element by xpath fail, I get 'Stale Element Reference Exception'.
But interesting that when I accidentally ignored popup and wanted to click somewhere else click was intercepted by popup.

Comment: Maybe try putting in some `sleep(5)` (5 seconds) for example and then find the close element by id or name and trigger mouse click on it. Please share some code that'd help understand the problem better.

Comment: @Surya Yes, sleeping helps. I try to not use it to avoid getting my tests too long, but seems as this popup content is loaded from somewhere else it took more time to get that element. Sadly that it was so simple, but I spent so much time wondering wtf is going on, aah xD

Answer (score 2):

I think the pop up is being added to the DOM after you click.
so you should:

1. click the //div[@class='promotional-wrapper'] element
2. Wait for popup [exact locator TBD]
3. then search for element you want to interact with

The popup WILL be in the DOM after you launch it. Unless the popup is another window, in which case you will need to learn to deal with switching to windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36429462/1387701